# Why doesn't this function work (waiting for an element in Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

Basically, we have a `setTimeout()` function that waits half a second before creating an element and appending it to the body. Then we have an async function called `foo()` that tries to locate that element (`while(!expression)`) and awaits a promise if it can't yet find it. The promise just waits a tenth of a second and resolves.

The way I envisioned this working is that the first five times the while loop runs, the element isn't found and the promise is resolved. Then on the sixth time, the `setTimeout()` function at the top creates the element, and the while loop expression resolves as true. That means that the `console.log()` inside the `foo().then()` expression is reached (and the code can continue.

I believe this a problem with timing. When the code that creates the element is taken out of the `setTimeout()` function, the code executes fine, so it looks like the while loop is running indefinitely before the top `setTimeout()` function can fire. Why is this? Is there a way to fix this without rewriting all of the code? It seems like this `foo()` function, which I have in a larger codebase, stopped working recently. Did something change in the way browsers parse Javascript?

Note: The idea behind `foo()` is that what I write inside the `then()` function should always wait for the element identified by `expression` to be created.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    const el = document.createElement('div')
    el.id = 'bar'
    el.innerText = 'Bar'
    document.body.appendChild(el)
}, 500)

const promise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
       resolve()
    }, 100)
})

async function foo(expression) {
    while(!expression) {
        await promise
    }
}

foo(document.getElementById('bar')).then(function() {
    console.log(document.getElementById('bar'))
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Some of the things that are wrong**

First off this:

```
async function foo(expression) {
    while(!expression) {
        await promise
    }
}
```

Will never do anything useful.  If you pass a truthy value for `expression`, then the loop will never run.  If you pass a falsey value for `expression`, then the loop will be an infinite loop with no way for the loop to ever stop because there's no code in the loop that ever changes that value of `expression`.

Also note that `expression` is passed as a value, not a function that can be called again so it has one and only one value when it is passed and that value will not ever change within this function.  So, testing it with a `while()` condition really doesn't do anything useful either.

Also, `await promise` will always be awaiting the same promise so it will delay the first time, but the promise will already be resolved for subsequent times so it won't add any delay.  `await`ing an already resolved promise does not delay any more.

Then, this:

```
foo(document.getElementById('bar')).then(function() {
    console.log(document.getElementById('bar'))
})
```

Is always going to pass the result of `document.getElementById('bar')` to `foo()` and that will either be truthy or falsey depending upon whether the `#bar` element exists in the document or not.  If it's truthy because it exists, then `foo()` will just resolve it's promise immediately because it will never enter the `while` loop.  If `#bar` does not exist, then `foo()` will just be in an infinite loop forever.

---

**Implementation Using setInterval**

If you're trying to "poll" for when an element exists, please just use `setInterval()` perhaps with a counter to limit how long it runs.  It's a ton simpler and won't be subject to any of these problems.

```
let cntr = 0;
const maxChecks = 100;
let timer = setInterval(() => {
    ++cntr;
    let item = document.getElementById('bar');
    if (item) {
        // found #bar
        clearInterval(timer);
        // do something with #bar
    } else {
        if (cntr > maxChecks) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            console.log("gave up checking for #bar");
        }
    }
}, 100);
```

---

**Implementation Using a promise with await**

If you really want to use a promise, you can do something like this:

```
function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));
}

async function waitForElement(id, maxWaitTime = 2000) {
    const start = Date.now();

    while (Date.now() - start < maxWaitTime) {
        let item = document.getElementById(id);
        if (item) {
            return item;
        } else {
            // wait a little and try again
            await delay(100);
        }
    }
    throw new Error("Element doesn't exist after max time");
}
```

This gives you a function that waits (up to maximum amount of time) for an element to exist and then either resolves or rejects the returned promise.

```
 waitForElement("bar").then(elem => {
     console.log("element exists");
     console.log(elem.innerHTML);      // show contents of DOM element
 }).catch(err => {
     console.log("element does not exist after max time");
 });
```

---

**A Runnable Snippet**

And here's a working version in a runnable snippet:

```js
// create #bar element after a bit of time
setTimeout(function () {
    const el = document.createElement('div')
    el.id = 'bar'
    el.innerText = 'Bar exists now'
    document.body.appendChild(el)
}, 500);

function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));
}

async function waitForElement(id, maxWaitTime = 2000) {
    const start = Date.now();

    while (Date.now() - start < maxWaitTime) {
        let item = document.getElementById(id);
        if (item) {
            return item;
        } else {
            // wait a little and try again
            await delay(100);
        }
    }
    throw new Error("Element doesn't exist after max time");
}

// wait for #bar to exist and output it's contents

 waitForElement("bar").then(elem => {
     console.log("element exists now and its content is '" + elem.innerHTML + "'");
 }).catch(err => {
     console.log("element does not exist after max time");
 })
```

Comment: @symlink - Did this explain and did the solutions work for you?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the value of `document.getElementById('bar')` is evaluated once and the result is stored in the `expression` variable. To make it evaluate every time within the while loop, you need to pass a callback that will cause the evaluation and then call it every time:

```
async function foo(callback) {
    while(!callback()) {
        await promise
    }
}

foo(() => document.getElementById('bar')).then(function() {
    console.log(document.getElementById('bar'))
})
```

Just notice that I wanted to help you solve this specific problem and show you what was wrong but I'm in no way saying that polling a query on the DOM is a good idea.

Comment: Still the same problem with `promise` though

Answer (score 0):

[Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/ac162c561ee43dd69eff38e1b354a41bb42c9eba/experimental/puppeteer-firefox/lib/DOMWorld.js#L549) provides three polling methods to wait for an element to appear in the DOM:

- [Interval Polling](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/ac162c561ee43dd69eff38e1b354a41bb42c9eba/experimental/puppeteer-firefox/lib/DOMWorld.js#L616)
- [DOM Mutation Polling](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/ac162c561ee43dd69eff38e1b354a41bb42c9eba/experimental/puppeteer-firefox/lib/DOMWorld.js#L564)
- [Request Animation Frame Polling](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/ac162c561ee43dd69eff38e1b354a41bb42c9eba/experimental/puppeteer-firefox/lib/DOMWorld.js#L593)

The `waitForPredicatePageFunction` will run outside of puppeteer, with no other Puppeteer dependencies.  There is also a brief explanation of the benefits of the various [types](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/4593413f7dafae04ba94ff8b999e76ed08692309/website/versioned_docs/version-10.1.0/puppeteer.framewaitforfunctionoptions.md).

Comment: What makes you think OP is using Puppeteer?

Comment: You an use the code without Puppeteer.

Comment: Puppeteer would be appropriate if you were loading a web page from nodejs and needed an HTML parser and a manufactured DOM system.  But, the OP appears to be running code in a browser where puppeteer is not necessary or appropriate (since the HTML is already in the browser DOM).

Comment: You can use the code in a browser.

Comment: Puppeteer runs in nodejs, NOT in the browser.  From within nodejs, it fires up it's own instance of the chromium or chrome browser engine so it can run HTML pages.  Running Puppeteer in nodejs does not have anything to do with what the OP is trying to do.  The raw techniques behind the DOM polling techniques are relevant (and you'd have to show the OP how to use them to solve their problem in a browser to be a good answer here), but not in the context of using Puppeteer at all.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was attempting to say. You can just use the polling code, not Puppeteer. The `waitForPredicatePageFunction` will run outside of puppeteer, with no other Puppeteer dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

A promise can only resolve exactly once, so if you re-use the same promise, only the first time the 500ms wait is honored.